# php edit record via jQuery attr

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am trying to edit the record in php but it is only edit the first record here is the demo html code along with the php

```
$s = mysql_query("Select * from student");

    while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($s))
    {
    echo'<div class="ammad">'. $sql["id"]."".$sql["Name"]."".$sql["Subject"].'</div>';
    echo '<input ammad="'.$sql["id"].'" type="submit" class="abc" id="check"/>';

    }
```

i have use the custom attribute in html is ammad

and i am trying to echo the value of each record but it is only showing the id 1 for each record this is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#check").click(function(){
    var b = $("#check").attr("ammad");
        alert(b);
        });
});
```

Comment: I hope you're cleaning those values before injecting them into the HTML. You may be vulnerable to a XSS attack.

Comment: Just a note for w3c compliance. When using custom attribute, please prefix 'data-' to your attribute. Here it should be like `data-ammad`

Answer (score 1):

Id must be unique for each element in html, made id unique. you can get attribute value using class name of button:

```
$s = mysql_query("Select * from student");

while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($s))
{
   echo '<div class="ammad">'. $sql["id"]."".$sql["Name"]."".$sql["Subject"].'</div>';
   echo '<input ammad="'.$sql["id"].'" type="submit" class="abc" id="check'.$sql["id"].'"/>';
}
```

get attribute value like this:

```
$(".abc").click(function(){
   var b = $(this).attr("ammad");
   alert(b);
});
```

Comment: it is alerting only one record the first one

Comment: do you want to get id of all the buttons? on button click?

Answer (score 0):

No doubt your jquery will run only on first row bcoz in home I'd is an unique selector.  So u should use class selector in jquery not the Id.use class ABC as selector. No need to a sign I'd.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(". abc").click(function(){
        var b = $(this).attr("ammad");
         alert(b);
         });
    });
```